# Play an audio in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to play a sound effect using javascript. It doesn't work for some reason.

Here's my code.

```
<body>
<audio id="xyz" src="whatever_you_want.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>


<script>
document.getElementById('xyz').play();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Sounds like `whatever_you_want.mp3` doesn't exist...

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Does the javascript error? Does nothing happen? Does the network call to the mp3 file occur successfully from the browser?

Comment: ♫ ♪ http://jsbin.com/yapeg/1/edit  ♪ ♫ Closing your question. Check the path to your .mp3 or if that file format is supported in the browser you're using.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Not really, the sound you play is OGG, and won't work under IE.
lllep: Check the compatibility of your browser : http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_audio.asp

Comment: Does your browser support MP3 files? What browser are you testing this in?

Comment: I am using chrome, i guess it supports.

Comment: @Illep enter the exact path-to-mp3 into your addressbar after your domain name / address. Do you hear anything?

Comment: @dooxe so? ... I don't understand your comment :\ As I've said, one should check for the extension is supported by HTML5 Audio for the desired browser...

Comment: Based on the information you've provided here, I don't think it is possible to answer your question, because no one can reproduce your problem. If you [Edit] your question to include answers to Joe Enos's questions and it might be possible to answer.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: So it can depend on the browser he uses (and not only on the javascript). OGG works on most of the browser but not on IE. MP3 works on most of the browsers, but not Opera.

Comment: @dooxe thanks for the reminder, I think this info will be useful to OP. So basically to cover most of the browsers we can conclude that one needs both `.ogg` and `.mp3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome,,
I tried your code in my personal editor , Your code is right !
Some advices to can run your code :
1- Use a famous editor like "Adobe Dreamweaver" or "Notepad ++ " because these programs will found the error and help you to fix it .
2- You should use tags `<html></html>` .
3- If this code don't run again , try it with another programming language .
**I advice you to try this code with my additions :**

```
<html>
<body>
    <audio id="xyz" src="whatever_you_want.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('xyz').play();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```